# Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet

Tags: angular, ionic4, router

When I want to navigate between too page, angular throws this error message :
Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet.

Comment: Already answered on following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55617772/angular-7-multiple-outlets-error-cannot-activate-an-already-activated-outle

Comment: I try this solutions, it remove the error but it didn't work